# Sending richText format in email (currently using SPUtility.sendemail)

Tags: email, rich-text, sputility

I have a list field that contains hyperlinks and richtextformat. To send the email I am using:

```
    Spweb web = spcontext.current.web;
    StringDictionary headers = new StringDictionary();

    headers.add("to","someone@email.com");
    headers.add("from","me@rmail.com");
    headers.add("subject","helloWorld");
    headers.add("content-type","text/html");  //default

    string body = (string) listitem["RichTextField"];

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){
         SPUtility.SendEmail(web, headers, body);
    });
```

It sends the hyperlinks fine but the rest is sent as plain text. Is this a result of Exchange or is RichText not the same as HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(string)listitem["RichTextField"];  does return with html tags for me, turns out what I was missing was an additional header tag

```
    headers.Add("fAppendHtmlTag","True");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SPField field = listitem.Fields["RichTextField"];
string body= field.GetFieldValueAsHtml(listitem["RichTextField"]);
```